# Binary backup of AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds

I am looking for a way to do a regular [binary backup](https://blog.cloud66.com/hot-backups-for-postgresql/) of my AWS RDS PostgreSQL database to use this copy locally and mount it in my docker postgis container. As far as I have understood, I cannot connect to the RDS host and do `pg_basebackup`.

So what is the best way to do this task?

The best workflow would be: There is an automatic daily binary backup stored in AWS S3. Then locally, some shell script to download the files to a folder that is mounted to the postgis folder.

Any ideas if that is possible?

I have one more additional requirement: I would like to exclude specific tables in the backup.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. That's one of the things you give up when you have Amazon manage your database servers for you. The best you can do with RDS is `pg_dump`. There is an S3 export feature, but it exports in Parquet format: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html

Comment: The database is expected to grow significantly. That is why I was looking for the toption to do a binary backup for a more efficient workflow. It das not seem to work with Parquet. Maybe I should look into AWS Database Migration Service

Comment: Hi, you might consider using RepliByte (https://github.com/Qovery/replibyte) to get a local copy of your production database. It's fast (written in Rust) and open-source.